# Excel : create chart from pivot merged with standard table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery, powerpivot

I need to merge data shown in the two charts below. Top right is a stacked bar based on the "Available Hours" table for Full and Part-time workers. Bottom right is a stacked bar based on the pivot of "Estimated hours" to show estimates of a team's project time. The dashed arrow indicates how I need a side-by-side comparison of each team's Estimated vs Available capacity vs Returned value.

[image]

I've tried adding the individual fields from "Available Hours" to the pivot in various ways but the values are duplicated across projects or teams and so totaled incorrectly.
Merging the table queries in the data model produces the nested tables as shown below

[image]

If I expand the data to chart it as the data is then duplicated (besides not being stacked) :
[image: close but no cigar!]
How is it possible to either create an intermediate data table, or create a dynamic chart that aggregates the data from the pivot and the base?

Manually manipulating the data isn't really an option as the data is obtained via a connection, is a much larger data set and changes regularly. I'm OK with VBA if that is needed?

**Source Data:**
Estimated hours for a team to fulfil a project
Region  Team    Project Project Hours   ReturnedValue
North   teamA   Project1    54  100
North   teamA   Project2    53  132
East    teamB   Project2    34  85
East    teamB   Project7    19  54

Team    FT Hours    PT Hours    Total Hours
teamA   100 50  150
teamB   97  35  132

Sample File:
[Sample file](https://filedropper.com/d/s/UdZ1Jf4d7Y9FbsD9M6IN33cWMcySPR)

Comment: How about boiling this down to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that other could benefit from a solution too? After all this isn't an individual consulting service.

Comment: That first chart is very bad dataviz practice. You shouldn't plot the total that way as it is renders the chart meaningless. Have a read here for some advice. https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/

Comment: Thanks - @Peter, I've reduced the data table further! The original and this are very, very much smaller than the actual problem.

Comment: @David - I agree...but it's not my choice. Besides, the visualization is the least of my worries, it's getting the data in shape that's the problem!

Comment: Can you post your sample data tables as text?

Comment: @David - have put text in the original post, and a link to sample xl file.

Answer (score 0):

The (partial) solution I implemented : use the Power Query Editor to create a new append query based on the two underlying data tables.